# kendo observable array sorting

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a observable array in a viewmodel.
I show the date of array with a template:

```
<table align="center">   
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-template="row-template" data-bind="source: client"></tbody> 
</table>
```

But if i want to sort array? and show the 'client' order by name or surname?

Answer (score 1):

If your data array is like this (as json, if not convert to json or databind using server)

```
[{name:'name1',surname:'surname1'},{name:'name2',surname:'surname2'},{name:'name3',surname:'surname3'}]
```

You can use this code for client side sorting.

```
$("table").kendoGrid({
  dataSource: {
     data:[{name:'name1',surname:'surname1'},{name:'name2',surname:'surname2'},{name:'name3',surname:'surname3'}],
     sort: {
        field: "name",
        dir: "desc"
     }
  },
  sortable: true,
  columns: [
     {
        field: "name",
        title: "Name"
     },
     {
        field: "surname",
        title: "Surname"
     }
  ]});
```

If i understand you right, this will solve your problem.

Comment: No without a grid. i want to see a list. yes is a json object.